# Cannot build RN App after integrating Sentry

Tags: android, react-native, sentry, react-native-sentry

**OS:**

- MacOS

**Platform:**

- Android

**SDK:**

- `@sentry/react-native` (2.0.0)

**`react-native` version:** 0.61.4

**Are you using Expo?**

- No

**Are you using sentry.io or on-premise?**

- sentry.io (SaaS)

---

**I have following issue:**

When I try to to build the project by this command
npx react-native run-android

It fires this error

> Task :sentry_react-native:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
> 570 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 567 up-to-date

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sentry_react-native:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 0
```

**Expected result:**

The project should be built without issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried first doing

`yarn add jetifier` and then `npx jetify`

Then building your app.
Try this and do let me know in case of any concerns.

Comment: it logged this line , Jetifier found 2571 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers... -- but actually same result in the end

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I switched

@sentry/react-native to version "^1.3.8"

looks it was a conflict with Gradle version